# Select mySQL based only on month and year

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my mySQL DB that has some rows. One of this row is a DATE, like this: `2012-02-01`

What I want to achieve is to do a SELECT with PHP based only on the year and month.

The logic of the SELECT will be the following:

```
$q="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE Date="SELECT HERE THE SPECIFIC YEAR AND MONTH"";
```

The specific month and year will be be passed from a `$_POST` variable, like this `$_POST['period']="2012-02";`

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use the BETWEEN statement

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 234):

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE Date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-01-31'
```

for January, 2000

Comment: Your query won't scale because it needs to do a full table scan unless there is some optimization in MySQL that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Is this true for `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM Date)`?

Comment: @aefxx this is not a personal blog, but a collaboratively edited Q&A site. So feel free to improve the answer if you feel so.

Answer (score 20):

If you have

```
$_POST['period'] = "2012-02";
```

First, find the first day of the month:

```
$first_day = $_POST['period'] . "-01"
```

Then this query will use an index on `Date` if you have one:

```
$q = "
    SELECT *  
    FROM projects 
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '$first_day' 
                   AND LAST_DAY( '$first_day' )
     " ;
```

One could also use inclusive-exclusive intervals, which work pretty good (you don't have to worry if the column is `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, nor about the precision:

```
$q = "
    SELECT *  
    FROM projects 
    WHERE Date >= '$first_day' 
      AND Date  < '$first_day' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
     " ;
```

---

**Security warning:**

You should properly escape these values or use prepared statements. In short, use whatever method is recommended these days in PHP, to avoid any SQL injection issues.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for between, I initially was using Year + Month functions, but such did not scale, nor use indexes.

Comment: @sobelito Yeah. I usually prefer the inclusive-exclusive intervals. Post updated.

Comment: Please escape these values or use prepared statements... 

Answer (score 11):

```
$q="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE YEAR(date) = 2012 AND MONTH(date) = 1;
```

Answer (score 9):

Here you go. Leave the computing to PHP and save your DB some work. This way you can make effective use of an index on the `Date` column.

```
<?php
    $date = $_POST['period'];

    $start = strtotime($date);
    $end   = strtotime($date . ' 1 month - 1 second');

    $query = sprintf(
        'SELECT *
           FROM projects
          WHERE Date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(%u) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(%u)',
        $start,
        $end
    );
```

**EDIT**
Forgot the Unix timestamp conversion.

Comment: It is index friendly, but strtotime gives you int and you need to convert it to date for mysql first.

Comment: It should be string concatenation, rather than sum operation: `$end = strtotime($date .' 1 month - 1 second');`

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you have a database field created_at Where you take value from timestamp.
You want to search by Year & Month from created_at date.

```
YEAR(date(created_at))=2019 AND MONTH(date(created_at))=2
```

Answer (score 8):

To get the specific month and year data from the table

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(column_name,'%Y-%m') = '2021-06'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use mysql [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) function consider just the year+month part of the date:

```
select * from table where DATE_FORMAT(column, '%Y%m') = '202105';
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic will be:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE Date LIKE '$_POST[period]-%';
```

The `LIKE` operator will select all rows that start with `$_POST['period']` followed by dash and the day of the mont

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html - Some additional information

Comment: -1 String operations on data internally represented as an integer!? You serious?

Comment: @Yaroslav Yes, highly efficient, I suppose :D

Comment: Without index. It first convert date value to string and than match that string. In MySQL any column type can be queried by LIKE. But still it will work :D

Comment: Little bobby tables anyone?

Comment: There is no need to be crazy about performance all the time, now do you. Sometimes the effort and time you put in something to make it work a couple of microseconds faster does not make any difference, but you lost that time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$q="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE Year(Date) = '$year' and Month(Date) = '$month'";
```

Comment: This also doesn't use an index

Answer (score 2):

Here, FIND record by MONTH and DATE in mySQL

Here is your POST value `$_POST['period']="2012-02";`

Just, explode value by dash   `$Period = explode('-',$_POST['period']);`

Get array from explode value :

`Array
    (
        [0] => 2012
        [1] => 02
    )`

Put value in SQL Query:

`SELECT * FROM projects WHERE YEAR(Date) = '".$Period[0]."' AND Month(Date) = '".$Period[0]."';`

Get Result by MONTH and YEAR.

Answer (score 1):

to get the month and year values from the date column

```
select year(Date) as "year", month(Date) as "month" from Projects
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by changing $q to this:

```
$q="SELECT * FROM projects WHERE YEAR(date) = $year_v AND MONTH(date) = $month_v;
```

Answer (score 1):

No one seems to be talking about performance so I tested the two most popular answers on a [sample database from Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-introduction.html). The table has 2.8M rows with structure

```
CREATE TABLE `salaries` (
  `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_date` date NOT NULL,
  `to_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `salaries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`from_date`);
```

Here are the tests performed and results

```
SELECT * FROM `salaries` WHERE YEAR(from_date) = 1992 AND MONTH(from_date) = 6
12339 results
-----------------
11.5 ms 
12.1 ms
09.5 ms
07.5 ms
10.2 ms
-----------------
10.2 ms Avg
-----------------


SELECT * FROM `salaries` WHERE from_date BETWEEN '1992-06-01' AND '1992-06-31'
-----------------
10.0 ms
10.8 ms
09.5 ms
09.0 ms
08.3 ms
-----------------
09.5 ms Avg
-----------------


SELECT * FROM `salaries` WHERE YEAR(to_date) = 1992 AND MONTH(to_date) = 6
10887 results
-----------------
10.2 ms
11.7 ms
11.8 ms
12.4 ms
09.6 ms
-----------------
11.1 ms Avg
-----------------


SELECT * FROM `salaries` WHERE to_date BETWEEN '1992-06-01' AND '1992-06-31'
-----------------
09.0 ms
07.5 ms
10.6 ms
11.7 ms
12.0 ms
-----------------
10.2 ms Avg
-----------------
```

**My Conclusions**

1. `BETWEEN` was slightly better on both indexed and unindexed column.
2. The unindexed column was marginally slower than the indexed column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that I use and it will return each record within a period as a sum.

Here is the code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT emp_nr, SUM(az) 
FROM az_konto 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-31 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY emp_nr ASC");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Mitarbeiter NR</th>
<th>Stunden im Monat</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$emp_nr=$row['emp_nr'];
$az=$row['SUM(az)'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $emp_nr . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $az . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
?>
```

This lists each emp_nr and the sum of the monthly hours that they have accumulated.

Answer (score -1):

It is so simple. You may use inbuilt MySql functions YEAR() and MONTH().

$query = "select * from table_name where MONTH($variable) AND YEAR($variable)";

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Using a PHP variable directly in an SQL query is a huge security issue

Answer (score -2):

Yeah this is working, but it returns one row only while there is several rows to retrieve using selected columns only.
Like SELECT Title,Date FROM mytable WHERE YEAR(Date)=2017 AND MONTH(Date)=09
returns only one row.

Comment: If you already know that your approach is not working (which really surprises me), why do you post it as an answer? Why not recommend a **working** solution instead?