# PHP MySQL Check If String Contains Query In Only First Few Characters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if there is a way to check the first few characters of a string without having to select the string from the database first.

I am making an advanced search feature to add on to my websites search feature. The advanced search feature allows you to search by date. The date in the database looks like `2/1/2012`. If the user enters `February`, I convert it to the number `2`. I then query the database using this line (not the exact line):

```
mysql_query(SELECT * FROM database WHERE date LIKE '%2%');
```

However, this returns all rows with the number `2` in the date. I would like to search only the first two characters for the number. Is this possible using a MySQL query, or do I have to do it the longer way?

Comment: Have a look at this question posted a few minutes ago:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104704/select-mysql-based-only-on-month-and-year/9104747#comment11437205_9104747

Comment: You should store dates as dates in the database, not strings.

Comment: Anywhere in the first two characters? Couldn't that possibly result in unwanted months, like 12 (December)? How about using the `OR` operator? `LIKE '02/%' OR date LIKE '2/%'`?

Comment: you may want to cast the field to date and do a comparison on month()

Comment: [Date types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html); otherwise there'll be far too much wheel-inventing.

Comment: Typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to know **how to query for records in a certain month**, which is an entirely different problem and can be solved much more elegantly than what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the [`Mysql Date Data Type`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) for your field.

Then you can search by ranges of dates and all other nice features you would like to add, as well as converting the date data to  present differently like:

`2/2/2012`

`Feburary 2nd`

`Feb 2 '12`

etc...

Check out the [MySQL date reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more functions.