# Showing data only from specific months

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to count rows from my database by looking up the year and month only but because it is stored as a full date like `2016-06-21` for example the day is irrelevant to what I am trying to retrieve.

I have tried the following method but I must be going wrong:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_list WHERE task_started_status = 3 AND task_end_date = MONTH(Date) = '06'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$jan = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo $jan[0];
?>
```

There is no output - basically I am wanting to check the task status (3 means it is closed) and the month and year it was closed in. This data is going to be used for my graph which requires a single value.

Comment: can you add table structure of `task_list`?

Comment: `task_end_date = MONTH(Date) = '06'` looks odd.  What about just `month(task_end_date) = 6`?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104704/select-mysql-based-only-on-month-and-year

Comment: `AND task_end_date = MONTH(Date) = '06'` - This part doesn't make any sense at all.  If you are looking for records where the `task_end_date`'s month is `6`, then you should use `AND MONTH(task_end_date) = 6`

Comment: @Siyual well there we go! Thanks for the tip!