# PHP/MySQL datetime field: get all entries in given month

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i have a table which structure contains lots of fields and one field '*booking_time*' of type `datetime`. E.g. values of *booking_time* are *2015-10-04 07:33:45, 2016-07-20 17:40:00* and so on...

In my code i recieve the month and the year as two serperate integer variables (e.g 1 to 12 for months and 2015, 2016, etc. for the year).
Now i need to get all table entries which have the matching year and month in the *booking_time* field.

How do i set up my mysql-query string to get the two numbers from the variables into the datetime format of mysql and then compare it with *booking_time* to get all the entries that correspond?

EDIT: My problem is the comparing of the two numbers with a mysql datetime field and not that i don't know anything about mysql queries.

Kind Regards

Comment: Yes. My Problem lies more into the comparing only the year and the month with a full datetime structure.

Comment: You can pull in Carbon which easily does all this for you (unless you want to manually do it).

Comment: @MubeenInamdar nice hint. But not what i need in this situation - i think i wrote my question too unclear.
But after having a look at Carbon, i will definetly bookmark it for future projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select mySQL based only on month and year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104704/select-mysql-based-only-on-month-and-year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with something like that:

```
SELECT * from the_table where MONTH(booking_time) = 10 AND YEAR(booking_time) = 2016
```

This would select anything from October 2016. Make sure to compare that and month, or you will get multiple years at some day.