# how can i select all data from database,comparing from input month from frontend to the date recorded in database which is format like this 2020/04/02

Tags: sql, vue.js

example i have choose the month of february having value of 2

```
birth_month: [
        {
          label: 'January',
          value: 1,
        },{
          label: 'February  ',
          value: 2,
        },{
          label: 'March',
          value: 3,
        },{
          label: 'April',
          value: 4,
        },{
          label: 'May',
          value: 5,
        },{
          label: 'June',
          value: 6,
        },{
          label: 'July',
          value: 7,
        },{
          label: 'August',
          value: 8,
        },{
          label: 'September',
          value: 9,
        },{
          label: 'October',
          value: 10,
        },{
          label: 'November',
          value: 11,
        },{
          label: 'December',
          value: 12,
        }

      ],
```

for example i choose february having value of 2, now i want to select all data from database where month is in february having value of 2,

suppose that the format of birth_date in database is like this 2020/02/09

```
 $query = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_information WHERE birth_date =  ");

            echo json_encode($query);
```

help how to achieve this . thanks
i may have provide less code but i know everyone has visualize the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select mySQL based only on month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104704/select-mysql-based-only-on-month-and-year)

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it by using MONTH() in mysql.

```
$query = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_information WHERE MONTH(birth_date) = inputedvalue ");

echo json_encode($query);
```